# How do I manage multiple nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects from a json object some thing like this:

```
productData = [

{   
    id: 'unique id',
    a: 'some value',
    b: 'some value',
    c: 'some value',
    offers: [{id: 'id',  a: 'some value', b: 'some value'}, {price: {id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}}],
    alterations: [{id: 'id',  a: 'some value', b: 'some value'}, {price: {id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}}],
    channels: [{id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}],
    terms: [{id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}]
},

{   
    id: 'unique id',
    a: 'some value',
    b: 'some value',
    c: 'some value',
    offers: [{id: 'id',  a: 'some value', b: 'some value'}, {price: {id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}}],
    alterations: [{id: 'id',  a: 'some value', b: 'some value'}, {price: {id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}}],
    channels: [{id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}],
    terms: [{id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}]
},

//so on ......

];
```

Where I need to either edit, add, remove data from any of the nested objects and send the whole modified object to server. I am finding hard time maintining the objects as all of them are inside one global object/array.

I thought of first creating separate arrays for nested objects looping the global array i.e. 'productData` and create the following:

1. offers array
2. alterations array
3. terms array
4. channels array

and then pass them to the view and then either update/splice/push to those individual array and merge them back into the global array `product` and send it to server, but what if I have about 50 global objects?

Then I need to loop through 50 objects and create array of objects?

example:

```
var termsArray = [];
var channelsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < productData.length; i++) {

    for(var j = 0; j < productData[i].termsArr.length; j++){
        termsArray.push(productData[i].termsArr[j])
    }

    for(var k = 0; k < productData[i].channelsArr.length; k++){
        channelsArray.push(productData[i].channelsArr[k])
    }
}
```

Then I can do any modifications on arrays created and finally push them back to the global object?

Need some suggestions in approaching this issue. One other way I can think of is getters and setters, but I am still new to it.

Comment: `offers: [{id: 'id'}, { a: 'some value'}, {b: 'some value'}, {price: {id: 'id', a:'some value', b: 'some value'}}]` this is horrible, it should be `offers: [{id: 'id', a: 'some value', b: 'some value', price: 'some value'}, ...]`. Who's producing this stuff??

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone I get this from my backend team who send the json object

Comment: It looks like they used some kind of straight conversion between a  table and a JSON object... I'm not sure. This is the least useful thing I've ever seen. While you look for an answer, I'd suggest talking to the backend devs. A JSON object should be more like a tree. I'm not sure if it's easy enough to follow my reasoning; if you have a field called `offers` and it's an array, then every element of the array should be an offer. You have a bunch of random bits of data in it, instead.

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone Actually you are right. I miss typed it adding more `{}` literals while posting the question. Updated the structure

Comment: I hate to ask, but are you *sure* that `price` isn't a field in the previous object of the `offers` array?

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone Yeah both `offers` and `alterations` has `price object`. Its like discount offer price and discount altered price after 3 month period

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone Any siggestions?